# Use observable to get the HTTP response

Tags: angular, observable

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  formData = {
    first_name:"",
    last_name:"",
    middle_name:"",
    mobile_number:"",
    email_address:"",
    password:"",
    confirm_password:""
  };  

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8000"));
    // how to use this returned Observable to get the actual response.
  }

  submittedDetails(){
      console.log('FirstName: ' + this.formData.first_name);
      console.log('LastName: ' + this.formData.last_name);
      console.log('MiddleName: ' + this.formData.middle_name);
      console.log('Email Address: ' + this.formData.email_address);
      console.log('MobileNumber: ' + this.formData.mobile_number);
      console.log('Password: ' + this.formData.password);
      console.log('Confirm Password: ' + this.formData.confirm_password);   
  }
}
```

- I am playing around with the above code to get the HTTP response. Right now, I am learning Angular. The reason to make a HTTP call on `ngInit()` is purely for learning purpose.
- I am using **Angular 6**.

**Difficulty/Issue:**

I able to make a request to my back end code and code inside `ngInit()` returns me an `Observable`. Now, how to use this to see the actual response received?

Let's assume Content-type of response could be anything for now. 
I apologize if I have understood anything wrong(in Angular context) here.

Comment: you need to sucbscribe to it in order to get the result `this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8000").subscribe(res => {console.log(res)});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: @David Kinda duplicate  but the OP there is dealing with `async` and `sync` scenarios. Here, I am just trying to get response from a simple HTTP request.

Comment: I am not sure who down voted. I agree that I need to search more, but sometimes getting the right result also depends on search keywords we put. I was helpless as I didn't reach the right destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must subscribe to observable:

```
this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8000").subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Note that by default `httpClient` expects to receive JSON and parses that for you. If your reply returns something else, you should modify the request.

Comment: You are correct. It expects `JSON` as a response by default. Is there way we can set custom `accept-type` ?

Comment: Frankly, I am not doing that often therefore I don't remember how. But you can [take a look here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the request in your component/service you have to subscribe to it.

```
 this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8000").subscribe(response => {
           // do some action
        });
```

Comment: should we unsubscribe http calls?

Comment: usually we subscribe in the store/component level and we unsubscribe by 
.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe.... and previously we declare 
 private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();